# Node.js Oracle installation error "NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb binary"

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to use oracle instant client (https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/nt/instantclient/213000/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.3.0.0.0.zip) with the node js version 16.15.0 in windows 10. After installed both and successfully set the environment variable path, when I run my file, am getting error like

"Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb binary for Node.js 16.15.0 (win32 x64)
Looked for C:\project\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-abi93-win32-x64.node, C:\project\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node, C:\project\node_modules\oracledb\build\Debug\oracledb.node"

But if I change the node js version into lower version like 10, it is working fine.
Anyone know how to solve the issue, and let us why it occurs.

Comment: What versions of node-oracledb?  Try upgrading.  The old versions were built for specific Node.js releases but the newer ones use Node.js's portable Node-API interface

Comment: The error isn't related to Instant Client.  The node-oracledb binary hasn't been found.   (It is this binary that would load the Oracle client).

Comment: This was resolved over Slack.  The old version of node-oracledb needed to be upgraded.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I am using the latest version of node-oracledb, but still getting the same error. Any help?

Comment: First, search for existing questions/answers that match your scenario.